# Can the .NET New Relic Agent be configured to log my application's log messages and caught exceptions?

Tags: .net, logging, azure, exception, newrelic

I am currently using New Relic for my .NET application hosted in Azure and in the New Relic UI I can see all uncaught exceptions that occur in my web app. What I would like to be able to do is log ALL messages and caught exceptions as well so that I can see them in New relic UI alongside the uncaught exceptions (that I currently see now). Has anyone ever done this before and if so can you provide a how-to or maybe some code for how you got this working?

I haven't been able to find much about this online except for making using the ['NoticeError' API call](https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/AgentApi) somehow. Is this the right approach or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After contacting New Relic support I found out the following:

- New Relic is indeed NOT a logging facility
- It does however allow you to log a single exception OR string message per web transaction

Therefore you can configure the NoticeError API call to log the highest level exception that gets thrown or a single error message string per web service or page request.

This error will then show-up in the New Relic UI under the Errors section within the Events tab.

Answer (score 1):

NewRelic is not logging facility! It is monitoring/analyzing facility. You have to shape your logging on your own. Using any logging framework you are familiar with, or creating your own.

I personally use a wrapper around the System.Diagnostics.Trace's static methods [WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/149a051x.aspx), [TraceError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w0w6s51.aspx), [TraceWarning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f15e7w4.aspx). Then I have them automatically transferred by the [Azure Diagnostics monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx). I would not raise an exception just to log something.